# Swift draw shadow to a uibezier path

Tags: swift, shadow, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a strange question. Even though I did read a lot of tutorials on how to do this, the final result only shows the bezier line, not any shadow whatsoever. My code is pretty simple :

```
let borderLine = UIBezierPath()
borderLine.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:0, y: y! - 1))
borderLine.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x!, y: y! - 1))
borderLine.lineWidth = 2
UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
borderLine.stroke()
        
let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0,height: 1)
shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 1
shadowLayer.masksToBounds = false
shadowLayer.shadowPath = borderLine.CGPath

self.layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)
```

What am I doing wrong as I dont seem to see anything wrong but of course I am wrong since no shadow appears. The function is drawRect, basic UIVIew no extra anything in there, x and y are the width and height of the frame. 
 Many thanks in advance!

Comment: did you set [self setClipsToBounds:NO] and [self.layer setMaskToBounds:NO]?

Comment: I have shadowLayer.maskToBounds = false, not the clips to bounds. Should it be self or shadowLayer? EDIT: set self.clipsToBounds, nothing happens

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I take this example straight from my PaintCode-app. Hope this helps.

```
//// General Declarations
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()


//// Shadow Declarations
let shadow = UIColor.blackColor()
let shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3.1, 3.1)
let shadowBlurRadius: CGFloat = 5

//// Bezier 2 Drawing
var bezier2Path = UIBezierPath()
bezier2Path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(30.5, 90.5))
bezier2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(115.5, 90.5))
CGContextSaveGState(context)
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadowOffset, shadowBlurRadius,  (shadow as UIColor).CGColor)
UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
bezier2Path.lineWidth = 1
bezier2Path.stroke()
CGContextRestoreGState(context)
```

Comment: I have paintcode myself, it gives strange errors when copying the code in view, thats why i tried to learn to do it myself but i dont seem to get it...Thanks for your effort though

Comment: I think it will make you happy to have the - removed (which I didnt add). Your answer helped me a lot, even if it was copied from an app. Cheers!

Comment: is it possible to draw the shadow only with the line stroke ?

Comment: `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` returns optional context so the whole code won't work. Downvoted

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the way to add a shadow-sublayer. You can easily use the following  function (**Swift 3.0**):

```
func createShadowLayer() -> CALayer {
    let shadowLayer = CALayer()
    shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    shadowLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    return shadowLayer
}
```

And finally, you just add it to your line path (CAShapeLayer):

```
let line = CAShapeLayer()
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50))
line.path = path.cgPath
line.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
line.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
line.lineWidth = 2.0
view.layer.addSublayer(line)

let shadowSubLayer = createShadowLayer()
shadowSubLayer.insertSublayer(line, at: 0)
view.layer.addSublayer(shadowSubLayer)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using the shadow properties of my shape layer to add shadow to it. The best part of this approach is that I don't have to provide a path explicitly. The shadow follows the path of the layer. I am also animating the layer by changing path. In that case too the shadow animates seamlessly without a single line of code.

Here is what I am doing (Swift 4.2)

```
    shapeLayer.path = curveShapePath(postion: initialPosition)
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = shapeBackgroundColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    if shadow {
        shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        shapeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    }
```

The curveShapePath method is the one that returns the path and is defined as follows:

```
func curveShapePath(postion: CGFloat) -> CGPath {
    let height: CGFloat = 37.0
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) // start top left
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (postion - height * 2), y: 0)) // the beginning of the trough

    // first curve down
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: postion, y: height),
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (postion - 30), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: postion - 35, y: height))
    // second curve up
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (postion + height * 2), y: 0),
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: postion + 35, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (postion + 30), y: 0))

    // complete the rect
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
    path.close()

    return path.cgPath
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the curveShapePath method ?

Comment: @cool_jb curveShapePath method returns the path of the line with wave. It takes the position and draws the wave at the centre of that position. I will edit the answer to include this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also still apply a shadow manually when drawing custom graphics using a CGGraphicsContext:

```
guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
ctx.saveGState() // allows us to revert

let offset = CGSize.zero
let blur: CGFloat = 5.0
let color = UIColor.red

ctx.setShadow(offset: offset, blur: blur, color: color.cgColor)
// Shadow will be applied to drawing commands after this point

let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5).setFill()
path.fill() // drawing command gets a shadow added

self.restoreGState()
// Shadow not applied to drawing commands after this point
```