# Border gradient for a custom tabBar

Tags: ios, swift, ui-design

I want to make a gradient border like the following picture:

[image]

But I don't know how do it exactly. What gradient color I should use to do it? How to set my view to show a border like the image?

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126271/swift-draw-shadow-to-a-uibezier-path

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a shadow, which is on CALayer, which you access from UIView.layer.  In this case since you only want part of the view to cast a shadow you need to use the shadowPath property.  The apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410771-shadowpath) shows you exactly how to accomplish this.